# Importing my svg creates weird lines

Tags: svg

When I import my svg file into blender some lines are gaps and some just aren't even there, is there a fix to this?[image: Original picture]

[image: SVG in blender]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you share the SVG file?

Answer (score 0):

An option might be to use Blender's own facility to trace a Grease-Pencil object, directly from your image (Right-Click menu, on a reference-image):

[image]

.. which can then be converted to a curve. My 2D curve, after conversion, kicked up a fuss about being filled, in its own 'Shape' panel. But a Geometry Nodes *Fill Curve* node did the trick.

Here, the curve, further subdivided and deformed, to test:

[image]